# Pandas - Create new column w/values from another column based on str contains

Tags: python, pandas, string, join, merge

I have two DataFrames. One with multiple columns and other with just one. So what I need is to join based on partial str of a column. Example:

**df1**

```
| Name     |       Classification       |
| -------- | -------------------------- |
| A        | Transport/Bicycle/Mountain |
| B        | Transport/City/Bus         |
| C        | Transport/Taxi/City        |
| D        | Transport/City/Uber        |
| E        | Transport/Mountain/Jeep    |
```

**df2**

```
| Category |
| -------- | 
| Mountain |
| City     |
```

As you can see the order on Classification column is not well difined.

Derisable **Output**

```
| Name     |       Classification       | Category  |
| -------- | -------------------------- |-----------|
| A        | Transport/Bicycle/Mountain | Mountain  |
| B        | Transport/City/Bus         | City      |
| C        | Transport/Taxi/City        | City      |
| D        | Transport/City/Uber        | City      |
| E        | Transport/Mountain/Jeep    | Mountain  |
```

I'm stuck on this. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want if both strings appear under classification?

Comment: I understand your question @JustinEzequiel, maybe my example wasn't very clear. First let me tell you that I'm on a very beginner level so this could be pretty simple. What I need is a way to join both Df and apply the correct category.

Comment: What I meant was what if the classification column has, e.g, "foo/Mountain/City/bar"?

Comment: Oh ok. If both appear it could be any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation does the trick:

```
def get_cat(val):
    for cat in df2['Category']:
        if cat in val:
            return cat
    return None

df['Category'] = df['Classification'].apply(get_cat)
```

Note: as @Justin Ezequiel pointed out in the comments, you haven't specified what to do when Mountain and City exists in the Classification. Current implementation uses the first Category that matches.

Comment: `lambda x: f(x)` is an uninteresting way of writing `f` I think

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dff={"ne":[]}

for x in df1["Classification"]:
    if a in df2 and a in x:
        dff["ne"].append(a)
df1["Category"]=dff["ne"]
```

`df1` will look like your desirable output.

Comment: @Kshitz Nice implementation. Side note: not matching classification items will give a weird outcome in df1.  The double if statement could be written shorter to `if a in df2 and a in x`.